# Ubuntu 20.10 freezes except for mouse pointer

Tags: freeze, 20.10

My Ubuntu froze yesterday, I had to restart.  Same today.  I see nothing in the `journalclt`:

```
-- Logs begin at Thu 2021-04-15 13:43:57 WEST, end at Sun 2021-04-18 23:21:17 WEST. --
Apr 18 23:01:55 mac2011-linux wpa_supplicant[880]: wlp3s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 7c:8b:ca:e3:5c:da [GTK=TKIP]
Apr 18 23:05:38 mac2011-linux rtkit-daemon[1054]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Apr 18 23:05:38 mac2011-linux rtkit-daemon[1054]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Apr 18 23:06:30 mac2011-linux rtkit-daemon[1054]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Apr 18 23:06:30 mac2011-linux rtkit-daemon[1054]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Apr 18 23:07:14 mac2011-linux systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Apr 18 23:07:14 mac2011-linux systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service: Succeeded.
Apr 18 23:07:14 mac2011-linux systemd[1]: Finished Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Apr 18 23:08:20 mac2011-linux /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1610]: (EE) event5  - Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 31ms, your system is too slow
Apr 18 23:09:10 mac2011-linux /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1610]: (EE) event5  - Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 38ms, your system is too slow
Apr 18 23:11:55 mac2011-linux wpa_supplicant[880]: wlp3s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 7c:8b:ca:e3:5c:da [GTK=TKIP]
Apr 18 23:17:01 mac2011-linux CRON[5205]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr 18 23:17:01 mac2011-linux CRON[5206]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Apr 18 23:17:01 mac2011-linux CRON[5205]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Apr 18 23:17:34 mac2011-linux rtkit-daemon[1054]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Apr 18 23:17:34 mac2011-linux rtkit-daemon[1054]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Apr 18 23:18:20 mac2011-linux systemd[1504]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
Apr 18 23:18:20 mac2011-linux dbus-daemon[1515]: [session uid=1000 pid=1515] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.104' (uid=1000 pid=5256 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.real --window " label="unconfined")
Apr 18 23:18:20 mac2011-linux systemd[1504]: Created slice app.slice.
Apr 18 23:18:20 mac2011-linux systemd[1504]: Created slice app-org.gnome.Terminal.slice.
Apr 18 23:18:20 mac2011-linux systemd[1504]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
Apr 18 23:18:20 mac2011-linux dbus-daemon[1515]: [session uid=1000 pid=1515] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
Apr 18 23:18:20 mac2011-linux systemd[1504]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
Apr 18 23:18:20 mac2011-linux systemd[1504]: Started VTE child process 5267 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 5259.
Apr 18 23:18:20 mac2011-linux systemd[1504]: app-gnome-org.gnome.Terminal-5254.scope: Succeeded.
Apr 18 23:18:34 mac2011-linux sudo[5276]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Apr 18 23:18:39 mac2011-linux sudo[5276]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Apr 18 23:18:39 mac2011-linux sudo[5276]:     alba : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/alba ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl --since=-10 minutes
Apr 18 23:18:39 mac2011-linux sudo[5276]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr 18 23:18:47 mac2011-linux sudo[5276]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Apr 18 23:18:58 mac2011-linux sudo[5283]:     alba : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/alba ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl --since=-10 minutes
Apr 18 23:18:58 mac2011-linux sudo[5283]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr 18 23:18:58 mac2011-linux sudo[5283]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Apr 18 23:18:58 mac2011-linux dbus-daemon[1515]: [session uid=1000 pid=1515] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Tracker1' unit='tracker-store.service' requested by ':1.2' (uid=1000 pid=1513 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs " label="unconfined")
Apr 18 23:18:58 mac2011-linux systemd[1504]: Starting Tracker metadata database store and lookup manager...
Apr 18 23:18:58 mac2011-linux dbus-daemon[1515]: [session uid=1000 pid=1515] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Tracker1'
Apr 18 23:18:58 mac2011-linux systemd[1504]: Started Tracker metadata database store and lookup manager.
Apr 18 23:19:03 mac2011-linux dbus-daemon[1515]: [session uid=1000 pid=1515] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Tracker1.Miner.Extract' unit='tracker-extract.service' requested by ':1.2' (uid=1000 pid=1513 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs " label="unconfined")
Apr 18 23:19:03 mac2011-linux systemd[1504]: Starting Tracker metadata extractor...
Apr 18 23:19:03 mac2011-linux tracker-extract[5291]: Set scheduler policy to SCHED_IDLE
Apr 18 23:19:03 mac2011-linux tracker-extract[5291]: Setting priority nice level to 19
Apr 18 23:19:03 mac2011-linux systemd[1504]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
Apr 18 23:19:03 mac2011-linux dbus-daemon[1515]: [session uid=1000 pid=1515] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Tracker1.Miner.Extract'
Apr 18 23:19:03 mac2011-linux systemd[1504]: Started Tracker metadata extractor.
Apr 18 23:19:13 mac2011-linux systemd[1504]: tracker-extract.service: Succeeded.
Apr 18 23:19:33 mac2011-linux tracker-store[5286]: OK
Apr 18 23:19:33 mac2011-linux systemd[1504]: tracker-store.service: Succeeded.
Apr 18 23:21:17 mac2011-linux sudo[5330]:     alba : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/alba ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl --since=-20 minutes
Apr 18 23:21:17 mac2011-linux sudo[5330]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

I update my system almost every day.  A few similar reports are on AskUbuntu.

Any idea?

Added after comment:

```
% free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       16304440     2439800     9884556      728660     3980084    12795216
Swap:       2097148           0     2097148
```

Comment: System "freezes" are often caused by running too many, too large programs and running out of available memory. Use `free` to see if you have swap space, read `man mkswap swapon fstab` to create some. Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV.

Comment: I have 16GB RAM but it may be filled by Firefox tabs after days.  I will watch this.

Comment: I find it suspicious that you have `0 Swap used`. What does `swapon;grep swap /etc/fstab` tell us? `sudo journalctl  -b 0 | grep -E 'swap|memory'` ?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash` and `top` (when the system has been running for a while) and `free -h` (when the system has been running for a while) and `sysctl vm.swappiness`.

Comment: @waltinator re: *"Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended"*... that's very very old school recommendation, and is way too much... unless you're hibernating.

Comment: I have added the requested information. I don't use hibernation but for hibernation the swap should be greater than the RAM.